# How to make an image stay exactly at the screen left side in Bootstrap, without ruining the text in the same row and its responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want an image to stay exactly on the left side of the screen(fix it to the left side). I want the image to "start" from the screen's side. I managed to do this with

```
position:fixed; left: -15px;
```

and it works from the viewpoint of the image, it starts at the screen's left side exactly on every screen I tested.
BUT it ruins other things, namely the text on the same row will be on top of the  picture, AND if I decrease the windows/screen size it will become more of a mess with the text.
What's a better solution?

My code:

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3" id="swoosh">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Title of the website</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.png">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want the first picture, so img1.png to be on the left, the title should be in the middle, and the logo.png on the right. The second image, the logo.png doesn't need to be fixed to the right, just img1 to the left.

I tried to provide the all the info you need, but I'm new here so please tell me if there's anything more you need!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Added fiddles.

As you can see, the black image does not start at the screen's left side exactly here:
http://www.bootply.com/bGJhH27MQO

The next fiddle shows you how the black image should be positioned, but it ruins the site:
http://www.bootply.com/sFeKODGOSq

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that replicates the problem? By adding position:fixed to a bootstrap col-md-3 element you are breaking bootstrap's default responsiveness etc. You might be better to remove padding or margin via css on that element instead, but I can't be sure without seeing the full problem in action.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/bGJhH27MQO

i would like the black image to start at the left, like here, you can see the problem:

http://www.bootply.com/sFeKODGOSq

Comment: Just answered there- let me know if it's still not what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your html almost works. As you found out, using a fixed position within Bootstrap's grid system doesn't work very well.

Rather than trying to fix the `<div>` to the left edge, you should try fixing the image to the left edge.  You don't need to use absolute positioning to do it.  You can use a negative margin-left value to shift the image to the left. See updated code below

```
#swoosh {
 margin-left: -15px;

}

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class="row outerDiv">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 imageDiv" >
       <img class="img-responsive" id="swoosh" ...
```

The actual value of the margin-left value is a little fuzzy.  The value of -15px is to offset the padding-left value in the Bootstrap's col-xxxx classes.  You will need to adjust the the value to meet your needs.

I've created a working version at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nodica/1/)

Comment: Great! Left-margin didnt work because I id-ed the div, not the image like you did. Thanks, its awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have the row element within a container - so unless you use negative margins you won't be able to move the element the whole way across. You could place that row within a container-fluid element which will remove the restrictions on the location but it would stretch the element the whole width of the screen

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <p>Navbar Code Here</p>
 </div>    
</div><!-- /.container -->
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" id="swoosh">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/7/71/Black.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <h1>Title of the website</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/red/red-01.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>     
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

You can then remove the padding on that left image by applying

```
#swoosh {padding-left: 0;}
```

to your css.

If you need to change the alignment of the columns in responsive views, you should start taking a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete to change the layout at the viewport reduces - perhaps using col-xs-6 etc to achieve the alignment you are after